# Creating IIS7 web application using PowerShell with Require SSL set to "Require"

Tags: ssl, iis-7, powershell-2.0, appcmd

I'm creating an IIS web site using PowerShell's [`New-WebSite`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee790605.aspx) cmdlet, and within that a web application using [`New-WebApplication`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee807831.aspx).

The SSL settings for the web application need to be set to *Require SSL; Require* as shown below.

[image: IIS SSL Settings]

For consistency, I would like to do this using only PowerShell cmdlets.

The *Require SSL* setting is easy; you just add the `-Ssl` parameter to `New-Website`.

However, the only way we've found to set the *Require* option is using [`Appcmd.exe`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx):

```
& $env:SystemRoot\System32\inetsrv\Appcmd.exe `
    set config "$WebSiteName/$VirtualDirName" `
    /section:access `
    /sslFlags:"SslRequireCert" `
    /commit:APPHOST
```

Is there a PowerShell alternative to this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had to add ***ssl*** to the value:

> Set-WebConfiguration -Location "$WebSiteName/$WebApplicationName" 
>       `-Filter 'system.webserver/security/access'`
>       -Value "**Ssl**, SslRequireCert"

Comment: The other options did nothing (including the -Ssl for new-website flag) - this worked fine (IIS 7.5, Windows Server 2008R2).

Comment: What is the -Value if you want to either ignore or accept SSL?

Answer (score 3):

Solution found, using `Set-WebConfiguration`:

```
Set-WebConfiguration -Location "$WebSiteName/$WebApplicationName" `
    -Filter 'system.webserver/security/access' `
    -Value "SslRequireCert"
```

Comment: Has anyone ever received this error while running the above command: There is no configuration defined for object at path IIS:\SslBindings.

Comment: I had the same error. Answer by arcain worked for me, but I had to remove <-name "sslflags"> part of it

Answer (score 3):

I used this method:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -PSPath "machine/webroot/apphost" `
     -location "$mySiteName" -filter "system.webserver/security/access" `
     -name "sslflags" -value "Ssl,SslNegotiateCert,SslRequireCert"
```

Answer (score 3):

If you get the error "There is no configuration defined for object at path IIS:\SslBindings" you need to set the PsPath parameter

-PSPath IIS:\Sites